# R3.8xlarge RDS database taking days to run query

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, rds

I currently have one table that contains about 12 million rows of reviews with columns:

```
id
productid
title
price
userid
profilename
helpfulness
score
review_time
summary
text
```

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT title, productid as p, count(text) as positive,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM `reviews` WHERE productid = p) as total
FROM `reviews`
WHERE text like '%my favorite book%'
GROUP BY productid
ORDER BY positive DESC;
```

It's basically looking for all of the productids that have "my favorite book" in the review text, getting a count of the number of reviews that match per productid and then the count of the total number of reviews for each of those productids.

I have this table in a database on AWS' RDS with the class set to the fastest I could see of r3.8xlarge however it's still taking days to run.

Now whats even stranger, at least to me, is that if I change the search for text to below:

```
SELECT title, productid as p, count(text) as positive,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM `reviews` WHERE productid = p) as total
FROM `reviews`
WHERE text like '%tim ferriss%' or
      text like '%timothy ferriss%'  or
      text like '%four hour workweek%'  or
      text like '%4-hour workweek%'  or
      text like '%four hour body%'  or
      text like '%4-hour body%'  or
      text like '%4 hour workweek%'  or
      text like '%4 hour body%'  or
      text like '%four hour chef%'  or
      text like '%4-hour chef%'  or
      text like '%4 hour chef%'
GROUP BY productid
ORDER BY positive DESC
```

And even lower the database class to m3.2xlarge, the query only takes under 20 min.

Am I missing something here?  Any advice would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: I would guess that your second query selects many fewer rows, even though there are more conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your query is more easily written using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT title, productid as p,
       sum(text like '%my favorite book%') as positive,
       count(*) as total
FROM `reviews`
GROUP BY productid
ORDER BY positive DESC;
```

Your original query filtered out products with no positive reviews.  If you really want this, then you can add:

```
HAVING positive > 0
```

After the `group by`.

Comment: Thank you, is this query faster / does adding the "HAVING" make it faster as well?

Comment: @maplater . . . This query should be faster because it is not doing a subquery for each row product.  The `having` clause would have minimal effect on performance, in my opinion, because it does the filtering after the aggregation (some effect, because the results still need to be sorted and returned, but I don't think those operations dominate the query processing time).

Comment: Wow, this query made the time go down to under 5 min! Does the subquerying really have that much of an effect?

Comment: @maplater . . . Based on your experience, I would say "yes".